# Number of total comment does not tally with the number of comment?

Tags: multisite, comments

**Please help me out, I don't know why i'm getting this...**

[image: Bug Screenshot]

I have a WordPress multi site network running, On the main website I got 2 comment notification... I approved one and i left one pending.

I opened the Advanced database cleanup pro plugin i have on my website to free some space on my database.. I cleared some saved transient, pending comments, Auto draft..

After the cleanup. I went back to the comment section.. Even though i have 3 comments count... I only saw two...

I opened my website database to check manually in the wp_comment table.. The number of item is 2..

I'm not sure where the 3 comment is coming from,,.. I need to delete it to attain the correct figure (2 comment)

Please help me out

Comment: You're not the first one to have wrong counts here, but I don't know if we ever got to the bottom of it. If there are only two items in the wp_comments table, I'd try the Query Monitor plugin to look at the SQL that WordPress is using for the comment count why it's wrong. I'd also look at the transients in the wp_options table in case the comment count is cached wrong there.

Comment: Are you sure those aren't just the approved comments and that approving the pending comments will show all 3?

Comment: Thanks guys, I was able to figure it out.... @TomJNowell

Comment: @SirOTee can you post the solution as an answer below for other people with this issue?